# How can I change a window's background when a mouse is over it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have seen how to change a `Button`'s `Background` by MouseClick or when the mouse is over it. How can I change a `Window`'s background when mouse is over it? I haven't seen something like this before... maybe someone can help me? 
This is the code which I used to change a `Button`'s background. I don't know what I need to change to do what I need.

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DelAll">
        <Setter Property="Button.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Head">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Fill="Transparent" />
                        </Border>
                        <Label Name="NameLable" Content="Delete All" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="Background" Value="#3500ACFF"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF00ACFF"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="NameLable" Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="NameLable" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Del">
        <Setter Property="Button.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Head">
                            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Fill="Transparent" />
                        </Border>
                        <Label Name="NameLable" Content="Delete" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Yellow"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="Background" Value="#3500ACFF"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF00ACFF"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Head" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="NameLable" Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseDirectlyOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="NameLable" Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource DelAll}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="150" Height="50" Margin="95,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Del}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="150" Height="50" Margin="95,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you try the same thing that worked for the button?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But in the end nothing happened and I decided to apply here

Comment: Its the same principle... please show what you have tried.

Comment: [“Can someone help me?” is not a question we can answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/).

Comment: Write some code for us

Comment: Okay, just give me 5 minutes. I didn't know English as well as you. I have some problems with edition of my question. Just give me 5 minutes and i will show you my code. Sorry for that

Comment: @BradleyDotNET here is the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do it for you, the `<Window.Style>` ... `</Window.Style>` is the relevant part!

```
<Window x:Class="ForStackoverflow.MainWindow"
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ForStackoverflow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>

    <Grid>
         Content..
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Its essentially the same as a button it's just that instead of creating a `Style` within the `<Windows.Resources>`, you set the `Style` of the `Window` using `<Window.Style>`. Hope this helps!